# What kind of the standard exception in python should I raise for a function which can only be invoked once

Tags: python, exception

I'm making a init function for my module, I would like to raise Some Exception when the user accidentally call it twice. What kind of the Standard Exception should I raise.

```
Class A(object):
    has_init = False

    @classmethod
    def initialize_class(cls):
        if has_init:
             raise Exception('xxx')
        has_init = True

A.initialize_class()
A.initialize_class() # should raise exception
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't want a simple `singleton` recipe or something?, also shouldn't it be `if cls.has_init:` and `cls.has_init = True`?

Comment: Why not just initialize the class at the appropriate time, like after creation?

Comment: You should just use `__init__`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could raise a runtime error, but it would be better to change your initializer so it doesn't cause damage if it is invoked twice.

This is probably a case where you should raise a custom exception rather than a built-in.

Answer (score 1):

The [SystemError](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.SystemError) is an option but the [RuntimeError](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.RuntimeError) may be the most appropriate

Answer (score 1):

You could raise `AttributeError`, as follows:

```
class A(object):
    @classmethod
    def initialize_class(cls):
        del cls.initialize_class

A.initialize_class()
A.initialize_class()
```

(Although I'd personally initialize the class inside the module at import time, rather than let the client code do it. If initializing has to be handled after import time, consider making the second call a no-op instead of raising an exception.)